# Specification of Scala compiler's intermediate code

Tags: scala, scalac, intermediate-code

Is there any formal specification or detailed description of the intermediate code generated by the Scala compiler (i.e. passing the `-Xprint-icode` option to scalac)?

Thanks.

Comment: care to explain the downvote(s)?

Comment: I've only upvoted). Didn't find any such docs yet, however you may guess some info from [compiler's stages](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~emir/bqbase/2005/02/11/scalaPhases.html) and respective scaladocs - at least you will know what is included, what is not

Comment: Miguel Garcia implemented the new backend and wrote an article about it last year which is at http://magarciaepfl.github.io/scala/#GettingStarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icode format is going away, with the introduction of the new `GenBCode` backend, which goes directly from scalac `Tree`s to ASM's bytecode representation. If I were you, I wouldn't invest time in learning it.

Instead, I suggest you print after `cleanup` instead (`-Xprint:cleanup`), which is the last phase before the backend, with scalac Trees, which are very easy to understand because they're basically Java code with a Scala syntax.

That said, if you insist on dealing with `icode`, I don't think there's any real documentation about it. But it almost has a one-to-one correspondance with the JVM bytecode: it has classes, fields and methods. And inside methods, there is a stack-based instruction set.

Comment: That sounds good, thanks)) I wasn't interested particularly in icode, but more exactly on the backend's generated code, whatever it is. Said so, is there any spec for the new backend? maybe a doc in progress?

Answer (score 0):

Look here for documentation for icode (page 35):
http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/150270/files/EPFL_TH4820.pdf